# Javascript carousel drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, drag

I'm doing a sort of carousel and I need it to work on touch devices as well...
Everything works fine but now that I'm trying to implement the mouse drag event I'm having few problems...

The HTML look similar to this:

```
<div class="mover">
    <ul class="wrapper">
        <li>
            <div class="t">
                <div class="tc">
                    <p>1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="t">
                <div class="tc">
                    <p>2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="t">
                <div class="tc">
                    <p>3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It has various controls that I omitted because doesn't need for this scope.

The js functionalities that I'm trying to implement at the moment look like this:

```
var startDragPosition = false;
var $mover = $('.mover');
var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');

function startDrag( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ( $wrapper.triggerHandler( 'isScrolling' ) ) {
        startDragPosition = false;
        return;
    }
    startDragPosition = event.pageX;
    $mover.bind(
        'mousemove',
        function( e ) {
            $mover.css({
                'marginLeft': -(300 + startDragPosition - e.pageX)
            });
        }
    );
}
function stopDrag( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $mover.unbind('mousemove');

    if ( startDragPosition ) {
        var currentDragPosition = event.pageX;
        var direction = false;
        if ( startDragPosition < currentDragPosition ) {
            direction = 'prev';
        } else if ( startDragPosition > currentDragPosition ) {
            direction = 'next';
        }
        if ( direction ) {
            $wrapper.trigger( direction );
            $mover.animate({
                'left': ((direction == 'next') ? '-=' : '+=') + 300
            }, 'slow');
        }
    }
    startDragPosition = false;
}

$mover.bind('mousedown', startDrag)
$mover.bind('mouseup', stopDrag)
$mover.bind('mouseleave', stopDrag);
```

The movement for the other controls are based on the `left` position of the `.mover` element.
What I'm trying to do is:

- when I start dragging I would like to see the item to move.
- when I stop dragging I would like to see the item to move to the next or prev stage if it exist.

I'm trying and trying but I cannot understand how to let it work properly... I think to be close to the solution...

JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ttt93/

Comment: I added a jsfiddle as well...

Comment: A couple of things: 1. The `bind()` method is deprecated. Use `on()` instead. 2. If you're open to using jQuery, you might as well look at some of the carousel plugins that already exist. At the very least, they'll give you some implementation and design ideas.